# How do I replace ALL external / preview for post and pages from Wordpress admin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress as a headless CMS and only using the API to deliver content. I therefore want to link to the actual site that is a Vue.js framework hosted somewhere else.

What I have here is almost replacing all the links EXCEPT the "View Page" that's in the WP Admin Bar. When I look into the source code of how it's getting the link, it's using `preview_post_link()` which I thought I had replaced the URL for?

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', 'filter_preview_link'); 
add_filter( 'preview_page_link', 'filter_preview_link'); 
add_filter( 'get_sample_permalink', 'filter_preview_link'); 
add_filter( 'get_sample_permalink_html', 'filter_replace_base_url'); 

function filter_preview_link( $permalink ) { 
  $base_url = get_field('base_url', 'option');

  if(is_array($permalink)){
    $url_data = wp_parse_url($permalink[0]);
    $permalink[0] = str_replace($url_data['scheme'] . '://' . $url_data['host'], untrailingslashit($base_url), $permalink[0]);
    return $permalink; 
  } else {
    $url_data = wp_parse_url($permalink);
    $permalink = untrailingslashit($base_url) . $url_data['path'] . (isset($url_data['query']) ? '?' . $url_data['query'] : '');
    return $permalink; 
  }

}; 

function filter_replace_base_url($html){
  $base_url = get_field('base_url', 'option');
  $html = str_replace(untrailingslashit(site_url()), untrailingslashit($base_url), $html);
  return $html;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the missing code...

```
add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'customize_wp_admin_bar_preview_links', 9999 );

function customize_wp_admin_bar_preview_links( $wp_admin_bar ){
  $base_url = get_field('base_url', 'option');
  $view_site = $wp_admin_bar->get_node('view-site');
  $view_site->href = $base_url;

  $view = $wp_admin_bar->get_node('view');
  $url_data = wp_parse_url($view->href);
  $view->href = untrailingslashit($base_url) . $url_data['path'] . (isset($url_data['query']) ? '?' . $url_data['query'] : '');

  $wp_admin_bar->add_node($view_site);
  $wp_admin_bar->add_node($view);
}
```